# Js difference between ?? and || with numbers

Tags: javascript

Trying to access the value of the page on the query I wrote this code:

```
const page = parseInt(req.query.page) ?? 1
```

But when I tried to use `page` it says that it's Nan. Changing the code in:

```
const page = parseInt(req.query.page) || 1
```

returns a normal integer instead. Why is this happening?

Comment: `NaN` is false-y, but it's **not** `null` or `undefined`. See e.g. the opening paragraphs of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator, which explicitly compare `??` and `||`.

Answer (score 0):

`||` will evaluate to the right-hand side if the left-hand side is falsey. The only numbers that can be falsey are 0 and NaN. If

```
parseInt(req.query.page)
```

evaluates to either of those, the whole expression will evaluate to the right side, the `1`.

`??`, in contrast, evaluates to the right side if the left side is `undefined` or `null`. `parseInt` will never return `undefined` or `null`, so

```
const page = parseInt(req.query.page) ?? 1
```

is equivalent to

```
const page = parseInt(req.query.page)
```